# testcontainers error too many concurrent requests

Tags: testcontainers

I'm using testcontainers in my test. I want to run maven test inside docker image when building container. It doesn't work as there is no docker runtime in the build container. Now I'm trying testcontainers cloud. I have a trial account. Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.9-eclipse-temurin-19 AS build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app

ENV TC_CLOUD_TOKEN=<MY TOKEN>
RUN curl -fsSL https://app.testcontainers.cloud/bash | bash
RUN cp ~/.testcontainers.properties /root/.testcontainers.properties

RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package
```

It fails with error `too many concurrent requests`

here is the complete log

```
Downloading https://app.testcontainers.cloud/download/testcontainers-cloud-agent_linux_x86-64

\033[0;32mSUCCESSFULLY DOWNLOADED!\033[0m
\033[0;90mVersion: "Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS/ubuntu:22.04.2 (22.04)" version=1.3.36.2210+2487868\033[0m

Launching \033[0;36mtcc-agent\033[0m...
2023-06-02T03:30:23.170Z --- INF Testcontainers Cloud Agent arch=amd64 os="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS/ubuntu:22.04.2 (22.04)" version=1.3.36.2210+2487868
2023-06-02T03:30:23.173Z --- INF Testcontainers Cloud Agent arch=amd64 os="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS/ubuntu:22.04.2 (22.04)" version=1.3.36.2210+2487868
2023-06-02T03:30:23.174Z --- INF Waiting up to 120 seconds for the agent to start...
2023-06-02T03:30:24.299Z --- INF Starting a listener...
2023-06-02T03:30:24.301Z --- INF Listening address=tcp://127.0.0.1:42289
2023-06-02T03:30:25.344Z --- INF Discovered endpoints count=38
2023-06-02T03:30:26.205Z --- INF Eligible endpoints count=38 endpoints=["zone-aws-ap-northeast-1-cluster-ap","zone-aws-ap-northeast-2-cluster-ap","zone-aws-ap-south-1-cluster-ap","zone-aws-ap-southeast-1-cluster-ap","zone-aws-ap-southeast-2-cluster-ap","zone-aws-ca-central-1-cluster-us","zone-aws-eu-central-1-cluster-eu","zone-aws-eu-north-1-cluster-eu","zone-aws-eu-west-1-cluster-eu","zone-aws-eu-west-2-cluster-eu","zone-aws-eu-west-3-cluster-eu","zone-aws-sa-east-1-cluster-us","zone-aws-us-east-1-cluster-us","zone-aws-us-east-2-cluster-us","zone-aws-us-west-1-cluster-us","zone-aws-us-west-2-cluster-us","zone-gcp-asia-east2-a-cluster-ap","zone-gcp-europe-central2-b-cluster-eu","zone-gcp-europe-north1-b-cluster-eu","zone-gcp-europe-southwest1-b-cluster-eu","zone-gcp-europe-west2-b-cluster-eu","zone-gcp-europe-west3-b-cluster-eu","zone-gcp-europe-west4-b-cluster-eu","zone-gcp-europe-west6-b-cluster-eu","zone-gcp-me-west1-a-cluster-eu","zone-gcp-northamerica-northeast2-a-cluster-us","zone-gcp-southamerica-west1-a-cluster-us","zone-gcp-us-central1-a-cluster-us","zone-gcp-us-east1-c-cluster-us","zone-gcp-us-east4-b-cluster-us","zone-gcp-us-east5-a-cluster-us","zone-gcp-us-east5-b-cluster-us","zone-gcp-us-south1-a-cluster-us","zone-gcp-us-west1-b-cluster-us","zone-gcp-us-west2-a-cluster-us","zone-vultr-ewr-cluster-us","zone-vultr-lhr-cluster-eu","zone-vultr-mex-cluster-us"]
2023-06-02T03:30:26.205Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=1 max_latency=15
2023-06-02T03:30:26.222Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=2 max_latency=15
2023-06-02T03:30:26.241Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=3 max_latency=15
2023-06-02T03:30:26.258Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=4 max_latency=15
2023-06-02T03:30:26.274Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=1 max_latency=30
2023-06-02T03:30:26.306Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=2 max_latency=30
2023-06-02T03:30:26.339Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=3 max_latency=30
2023-06-02T03:30:26.371Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=4 max_latency=30
2023-06-02T03:30:26.402Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=1 max_latency=60
2023-06-02T03:30:26.463Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=2 max_latency=60
2023-06-02T03:30:26.528Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=3 max_latency=60
2023-06-02T03:30:26.592Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=4 max_latency=60
2023-06-02T03:30:26.656Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=1 max_latency=120
2023-06-02T03:30:26.778Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=2 max_latency=120
2023-06-02T03:30:26.900Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=3 max_latency=120
2023-06-02T03:30:27.022Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=4 max_latency=120
2023-06-02T03:30:27.143Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=1 max_latency=240
2023-06-02T03:30:27.386Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=2 max_latency=240
2023-06-02T03:30:27.629Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=3 max_latency=240
2023-06-02T03:30:27.872Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=4 max_latency=240
2023-06-02T03:30:28.113Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=1 max_latency=480
2023-06-02T03:30:28.594Z --- INF Trying to find a server attempt=2 max_latency=480
2023-06-02T03:30:28.822Z --- INF Obtaining a worker cached= diagnosis=false endpoint=https://eks-us.workloads.testcontainers.cloud/lease?zone=vultr-ewr index=0
2023-06-02T03:30:28.823Z --- INF Picked server id=zone-vultr-ewr-cluster-us index=0 responded=227 server=66.135.28.13
2023-06-02T03:30:28.824Z --- INF Start of session client_session_id=6de00bd0-e787-4ec5-a28e-b5d026dff260
2023-06-02T03:30:30.405Z --- INF Opening direct connection endpoint=66.135.28.13:32122
2023-06-02T03:30:30.405Z --- INF Obtained a worker datacenter_id=zone-vultr-ewr-cluster-us endpoint=https://eks-us.workloads.testcontainers.cloud/lease?zone=vultr-ewr index=0 worker_id=126a6552-7e59-4829-b261-f78bfe8d5a2b
2023-06-02T03:30:30.429Z --- INF Initial connection successful connector=tunnel.direct
2023-06-02T03:30:58.637Z --- INF Unable to obtain a lease body="{\"title\":\"Too many leases active on cluster for user\",\"status\":429}" status=429
ERROR: too many concurrent requests
2023-06-02T03:32:23.043Z --- FTL Timed out waiting for agent to be running addr=127.0.0.1:42289
Error response from daemon: The command '/bin/sh -c curl -fsSL https://app.testcontainers.cloud/bash | bash' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How do I make it so that it doesn't make concurrent requests? I don't mind if it runs much slower. I want test with the trial first but it doesn't work with a single test

Answer (score 2):

You are facing the limitation of [trial accounts](https://knowledge.testcontainers.cloud/how-are-trial-accounts-restricted) here, regarding service accounts.

However, from the Dockerfile you shared it is unclear, where the parallel leases originate, especially since the error already occurs when executing the bash script. Did you by any chance run another build at the same time?

You can also check out the dashboard at https://app.testcontainers.cloud to make sure, there is no active lease for this service account while you are running the Docker build.

Lastly, feel free to [join our Slack](https://slack.testcontainers.org/) to get faster support.